# Node.js Handlebars display data from mySQL database to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bootstrap-modal, express-handlebars

I have a node.js and handlebars CRUD app.

I want to display data from mySQL database to a bootstrap modal but i can't render the modal, (it wont show). How do i show the data into the modal? My existing code in app.js:

```js
//edit address details
app.get('/edit-address/:id', function (request, response) {
  var id = request.params.id
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses"
  var edit;
  console.log(id)
  connection.query(sql, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
      console.log(results[index].id)
      if (id == results[index].id) {
        edit = results[index]
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(edit)
    response.render('partials/user/editaddress_modal', { edit: edit });
    // data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#editaddress-modal"
  });
})
```